# Android: use of unsigned apk?

Tags: android

There are lot of discussions on signed and unsigned apk in android. I found that we cannot install the unsigned application in any how on phone or emulator. We have to sign our application either by debug or own certificate.

If this is so, then why there is unsigned apk inn android. What is it's use, if it can not be installed in phone or emulator?

Please explain.

Comment: Because the building system have to first generate an unsigned version, so then it can use `jarsigner` to generate the signed version. It's only there because the debugger doesn't bother on deleting it.

Comment: `It's only there because the debugger doesn't bother on deleting it`. ?? That can never be a reason for it's existence.

Comment: I'm not aware of discussions about signed and unsigned apk's. I'm also not aware that I have to sign my apps in order to use them. I made a lot of apps but never did something to sign them and they run on all kind of devices. I'm also not aware that there are signed and unsigned versions of apps in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The unsigned apk exists so that you can pass it to the next stage of the process to sign it.

For a single developer who codes, signs, and uploads to the app store all by themself, there's unlikely to be the need for ever looking at the unsigned apk.

For a larger organization, where the only people who have access to the signing keys, and the Play Store account credentials, are not the same person as the programmer, the programmer may need to pass the unsigned apk to the other people so that they can do their tasks.

Comment: I am not sure about the reasons you provided!

Answer (score 0):

### Plausible Reason

Unsigned apks can still be installed into an emulator. Also, signing each time can be a little slow, as compiling and signing might be quite a long process to do multiple times a day. An unsigned APK can still be used and installed in emulators, so the process is a little faster.

### Corporative reason

In some companies, there's a job called **Release manager** or **Build manager**, which is the one that takes applications or web versions, and processes them to make them available online, maybe optimizing the code or something like that, compiling to multiple platforms. [Here's more information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Release_management).

Now, imagine that there's only a single Release manager in a company, but deals with 10 different projects that go into 5 different stores each. He has all the accounts and passwords for different markets and stores. A developer shouldn't have to bother with all the different accounts, and upload all the stuff here and there. Plus there are some optimizations or steps a Release manager might be able to automate for each different market.